# XPath,XSL: Test if node exists which has multiple children with special attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to find a way to do operations based on whether there exists a node which has two children with special attributes. So given this data:

```
<A>
  <B attribute1="X"/>
  <B attribute2="Y"/>
</A>
<A>
  <B/>
</A>
```

I only want to get true if there exists an element `A` which has one element `B` with `attribute1="X"` and one element `B` with `attribute2="Y"`, like in the data example.
So my start was

```
<xsl:if test="(boolean(//A/B[@attribute1='X'] and B[@attribute2='Y'))">
```

This does not work, and the best I could do so far is to evaluate if there is one Node `A1` with a child that has `attribute1 = X` and one Node `A2` with a child that has `attribute2 = Y`, but `A1` and `A2` can be different Nodes.

Comment: Could you ever have a a single `B` element with both a `attribute1` and `attribute2` attribute? i.e. `<B attribute1="X" attribute2="Y"/>`

Comment: if the XML structure correct? Maybe I am wrong but attribute names should be inside quotation marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'boolean(//A[B[@attribute1="X"] and B[@attribute2="Y"]])'
```